# How to access show() from foo.py?

Tags: python, import, module

foo.py

```
def show():
    print("x is from foo")
```

bar.py

```
def show():
    print("x is from bar")
```

foobar.py

```
from foo import *
from bar import *
show()
```

I want to access the `show()` function from `foo.py`.

My attempt:

foobar.py

```
from foo import *
from bar import *
#Don't change the above two lines. Keep them as it is. 
import gc 

show() #Calls show() from bar.py

found = [] 
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if type(obj) == type(show):
        found.append(obj)

print(found)
```

How to access `show()` from `foo.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foobar.py

```
from foo import *
from bar import *
#Don't change the above two lines. Keep them as it is. 
import gc 

show() #Calls show() from bar.py

found = [] 
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if type(obj) == type(show):
        if obj.__name__ = show.__name__:
            found.append(obj)

found[0](0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, because of the way you are **importing the files** and because of both of them having the same **function name** **("show")**, **only** the function from **"bar.py"** will be accessible, **overwriting** the function of "foo.py", because "**foo.py"** got **imported first**.

Thus, you need to change your import method.
The code should look like:

```
import foo
import bar
import gc 

bar.show() #Calls show() from bar.py
foo.show() #Calls show() from foo.py

found = [] 
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if type(obj) == type(show):
        found.append(obj)

print(found)
```

Take care

Comment: I edited the question. Please keep those two lines as it is even if the show from bar.py overshadows the show from foo.py. I want a solution keeping them same.

Comment: Don't try to import ```foo``` again.

Comment: @Niraj Raut Well, could you tell me why tho? Because that would be the simplest way to fix the issue. You should never perform 'from x import *' if functions/vars etc. that have to be accessed would be overwritten by doing so. Bad decision.

Comment: I know that it's a bad code, but this is just a fun problem that I wasn't able to solve. Could you please solve it?

Comment: @NirajRaut it is not just bad code, it is just impossible... Once you did `from bar import *` the `show` name in your code is now associated with the function from `bar`. And since you don't have the name `foo` available you can't access it...

Comment: @NirajRaut so I see you have your answer... Anyway, it still doesn't tell how you can call specifically one of them. You can't know from what module they came by the address...

Comment: @NirajRaut No because I don't know what is `func_name`... Why  don't you ask the author?

Answer (score 0):

you can try try `foo.show()` and to call the bar use `bar.show()`

Comment: Still has to change the import method in order to make your suggestion work out.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: in that case you should change your `import` statetments to `import foo` and `import bar`.

Comment: It is not *my* imports... Not my question, but the question says to don't change the imports and this is why the above will raise an error... @jottbe

Comment: Yes, exactly. Like make it run without fixing the bugs.